# How to quit a function if variables changes in java ? (restart server)

Tags: java, client-server

Using Java, I am looking for a way to quit a function if one variable changes. Idea ?

Something like this :

```
public class MyServer{

    private int port = 6789;


    public static void main(String args[]){
         startServer(port);    // My server is listenning on port 6789 first
    }

    public void handlePortChange(){
         // if 'port' changes, restart server
    }

    public void setPort(int p) { port = p; }
}


public Class MyServerUI{

    JTextField textField;
    MyServer server;

    // Constructor...
    MyServerUI(MyServer s){
         server = s;
    }

    // Method that
    public void openUI(){

         // My window
         JFrame  f  = new JFrame("My Server");
         f.setVisible(true);

         // a JtextField
         t = new JTextField("New port");
         f.add(t);

         // a button
         JButton b = new JButton("Change port");
         b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   // Changing the port
                   server.setPort(Integer.parseInt(t.getText()));
                   // method that restart server if port changes
                   server.handlePortChange();   
              }
         });
         f.add(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would your server's port suddenly change...?

Comment: just if users want to change it

Comment: IMO, I would recommend moving to a configuration, and then if they want to change they would need to shut the server down, rather than hot-swapping a port.

Answer (score 1):

In your UI class, start a new server if the port has been changed. Let the old server die when all requests have been handled.

```
public void doPortChange() {
    MyServer oldServer = this.server;
    this.server = startServer(newPort);
    oldServer.exitGracefully();
}
```

This way your old server will serve until it dies. Writing exitGracefully() is left to the user as an exercise :-)